# JQuery scroller to load dynamic data via ajax

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

Currently I'm using a marquee html tag to scroll data within a div tag

eg `<marquee align="Top" direction="up" loop="-10" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="100" style="height: 100px; padding-right: 5px;" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" width="100%">DATA COMES HERE</marquee>`

What I want is the same effect only I want to do it using JQuery and load content dynamically while the content scrolls in the marquee tag, is this possible and if so, how can I do this using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This [plugin](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) will do it for you, but by no means use a `marquee` tag. It has long been deprecate by W3C.